# Menu return null in android

Tags: android, android-menu

Hi this is my first question. i am learning android. here i am trying to setup menu icon top menubar.
I have added sets of item in menu. i want to manage icon from activity.
I am trying to show hide menu icon.
Menu return null in `onCreate`. 
Is there any other way to manage `menu` icon dynamically ? 
please help.

This is the `activity` class code snippet where i am trying to manage menu.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMenu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menuBar);//here Menu return null
    mMenuItem = mMenu.getItem(2);
    mMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    mMenuItem.setVisible(true);
  }
```

will appreciate your help. thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `inflate` menu to get `MenuItem` in `activity` method `onCreateOptionsMenu`  and then try to get `menu.getItem`like this :

```
    @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
   MenuItem item=menu.getItem(2);
   item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
   item.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: here also getting null: SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.getItem(2).getActionView();// return null
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

Comment: @AmitMaddheshiya have you added `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` for an item in menu xml

Answer (score 1):

Dont put it on your onCreate because your menu is initialized in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    mMenuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    mMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    mMenuItem.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Just follow the bellow instruction:**

**Step 1:**
You need to inflate menu item from **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)**
**Step 2:**
 You need a  **MenuInflater** object that you can get using **getMenuInflater()** 
 API. Like:  **MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();**
**Step 3:**
 Inflate you **menu xml** file like:  **inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bottom_nav, 
 menu);**
**Step 4:**
 You have to get menu object for specific item like : MenuItem menuItem = 
 menu.getItem(index). Here **Index is the number** depending on which menu item's 
 object you want to get.

Full code example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bottom_nav, menu);

      MenuItem menuItem  = menu.getItem(0);

     return true;
}
```